# Tracking mysql DML operations Source

Tags: mysql

we have one table which will get insert or update from 10 different jobs.
we need to track each DML operation with its source i.e job name.
we have used audit tables and triggers to get old and new table data but we are not able to track job which is responsible for that DML operation.

is it possible to track DML operation source ?

Note : in this case jobs include few procedures and few queries.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to have different users for your jobs.
Then you can select / insert `USER()` in your audit tables.

Apart from that there's no built-in MySQL feature that does this.

In my company we've written our own tool through which DML statements are fired to track which employee is responsible for which data modifications.